# Micrometer does not create and increment metrics in a row or overrides

Tags: prometheus, quarkus, micrometer

I have an implemented interface as follows where I increment the value of a metric.

```
   @Override
    public void IncrementForPacket(PppoeAgentStatTypes statType, PppoeAgentCounters packetType, PppoeAgentCounters errorType) {
        this.registry.counter(statType.getCounterType(), Tags.of("type" , packetType.getCounterType(), "error", errorType.getCounterType())).increment();
        this.registry.counter(statType.getCounterType(), Tags.of("type", packetType.getCounterType())).increment();
    }
```

When I trigger this method, the thing I see is as follows;

```
# TYPE pppoe_packet_received counter
# HELP pppoe_packet_received  
pppoe_packet_received_total{error="ac_system",type="pads"} 1.0
```

Why the second line is not applied by micrometer or prometheus? Is it something to do with tags name being same like?

Answer (score 0):

The Prometheus client does not let you having two time series that are only different in list of tag keys. Either change the name of one of them or attach the same list of tag keys.

```java
this.registry.counter(
    statType.getCounterType(),
    Tags.of(
        "type", packetType.getCounterType(),
        "error", errorType.getCounterType()
    )
).increment();

this.registry.counter(
    statType.getCounterType(),
    Tags.of(
        "type", packetType.getCounterType(),
        "error", "none"
    )
).increment();
```